# woocommerce rest api v1 date filters

Tags: woocommerce-rest-api

I am using WooCommerce rest api v1 in which I am trying to fetch all customers created in the month of June 2016. Here is the code I am using :-

```
$customers = $woocommerce->get('customers', array( 'filter[date_created_min]' => '2016-06-01', 'filter[date_created_max]' => '2016-06-30' ) ) ;
```

Unfortunately it is returning all the records and is ignoring the filter. Below is example of 1 of the record it has returned in the array :-

```
Array
(          
        [id] => 3
        [date_created] => 2016-08-08T15:26:49
        [date_modified] => 2016-08-10T22:17:44
        [email] => manager@manager.com
        [first_name] => Shop
        [last_name] => Manager
        [username] => Manager
        [last_order] => Array
            (
                [id] => 
                [date] => 
            )

        [orders_count] => 0
        [total_spent] => 0.00
        [avatar_url] => http://2.gravatar.com/avatar/?s=96
        [billing] => Array
            (
                [first_name] => shop
                [last_name] => manager
                [company] => test company 1
                [address_1] => test
                [address_2] => 
                [city] => test
                [state] => PB
                [postcode] => 1111
                [country] => test
                [email] => shop@manager.com
                [phone] => 123456
            )

        [shipping] => Array
            (
                [first_name] => shop
                [last_name] => manager
                [company] => test company 1
                [address_1] => test
                [address_2] => 
                [city] => test
                [state] => PB
                [postcode] => 11111
                [country] => test
            )
```

Please help me know the correct date filter. I have already tried the 'created_at_min' / 'created_at_max' but it is not working. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am joining in on this as I try to do the same with the modified date. I will add an answer if I do find one

Comment: I have a similar problem as I wish to filter on meta data. Did you find a solution?